# Natural Key Audit Table

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm designing SQL Server tables with Natural Keys instead of a Surrogate Keys for the Primary Key. The problem I've run into is that it doesn't work well with the Audit table format that I've used with Surrogate Key tables in the past. Typically I'll create an audit table that has the same columns as the table being audited. A trigger on the table being audited writes a new row to the audit table that matches the state of the row before update or delete. To enforce integrity I use both the Surrogate Key and modified date columns as a composite PK for the table. If I don't use a Surrogate Key then I cannot track changes if one of the columns that make up the composite key changes.

```
Log table example with Surrogate Key:

LogId (PK)
LogType
Data
ModifedDate
ModifedBy

LogAudit Table for Log table with Surrogate Key:

LogId (PK)
LogType
Data
ModifedDate (PK)
ModifedBy 


Log table example with Natural Key:

LogType (PK)
Data
ModifedDate (PK)
ModifedBy

LogAudit Table for Log table with Natural Key:
LogType 
Data
ModifedDate
ModifedBy
```

How do you track changes for Natural Key Log table record in the Audit table if LogType or ModifiedDate change?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Your basic design seems fine (the PK of the audit table is the PK of the source table plus a timestamp of some kind), so it isn't obvious what your problem actually is. It might also be helpful if you edit your question to show your table structures as real DDL instead of text, to remove any ambiguity about what the keys really are. And if your problem is populating the audit table, then how are you trying to do it and what difficulties are you having?

Comment: If I use the Natural Key version and either the LogType or ModifiedDate change, then I lost the link to reference the older records I've audited. Unlike the surrogate key version, I can query on logID and find the history of changes in the Audit table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the basic concept here.

If it is true that `{LogType, ModifedDate}` is a natural key in the `Log` table (case 2), then it is also true that it is an alternate key (AK) (unique) in the first example.

So the `Log` table in the first example would look like this.

```
LogId        (PK)
LogType      (AK1.1)
Data
ModifedDate  (AK1.2)
ModifedBy
```

So, for a given `{LogID}` the `{LogType, ModifedDate}` can not change, and vice versa.

But, this is not what you are trying to accomplish. The answer is probably that your `Log` table does not have "natural key" in the first place.

---

**EDIT** as per comments

As a rule-of-thumb, for creating a row-based audit table:

1. Copy the original table structure (columns).
2. Add `ChangedAt` (datetime) and `ChangedBy` columns to the table.
3. Add `ChangedAt` column to the original PK.
4. Add copy of PK columns to the table. This is to capture any PK changes.
5. Add FKs with ON UPDATE CASCADE, ON DELETE NO ACTION. This prevents hard-deletes, so use soft deletes.
6. Populate from an AFTER INSERT, UPDATE trigger on the original table.

*Example 1*

```
      Table: {ID, SomeData}                               ; key: {ID} 
audit table: {ID, SomeData, ChangedAt, ChangedBy, ID_CPY} ; key: {ID, ChangedAt}
```

*Example 2*

```
      Table: {UserID, UserOrderNo, SomeData}                       ; key: {UserID, UserOrderNo} 
audit table: {UserID, UserOrderNo, SomeData, ChangedAt, ChangedBy, UserID_CPY, UserOrderNo_CPY} ; key: {UserID, UserOrderNo, ChangedAt}
```

*Example 3* (as per your description)

```
      Table: {LogType, ModifedDate, SomeData}                       ; key: {LogType, ModifedDate} 
audit table: {LogType, ModifedDate, SomeData, ChangedAt, ChangedBy, LogType_CPY, ModifedDate_CPY} ; key: {LogType, ModifedDate, ChangedAt}
```

Comment: I don't think "ModifiedDate" can be part of a natural key here, because it's not an attribute of the entity being modeled. It's an attribute of the row the entity's attributes are stored in.

Comment: Maybe the ModifiedDate is the problem in this example. I'm using it for two things, first to capture the date of the event, and then I update it if the record changes. So it is an attribute of the entity for date of the event. So I could create another column called LogEventDate and make that the PK and it would be the Natural Key. It would work in the audit scenario because the value wouldn't change. So my question still exists, since some Natural Key values can change, what would be an Audit strategy for capturing changes when Natural Key values change?

Comment: @Josh -- for a given row (tuple) the columns in a composite key can NOT change, if it can it is not a key. Think ID -- if ID changes it is a different record.

Comment: @Josh -- suppose you have an order table with a key {UserID, UserOrderNo} then an audit table may have a key {UserID, UserOrderNo, ChangedAt}. NOte that if a USerID or UserOrderNo changes, it is not the same order ..

Comment: @DamirSudarevic, surrogate keys don't change value, but natural keys can because they part of the data that makes up the record. In your example, if there was a new business workflow that allowed orders to be merged, you would update the UserOrderNo value and want to audit the update. Whether you consider it the same order or not, you would still want to audit the record change otherwise you would lose its history.

Comment: @Josh - ok I think I finally understand what you are asking -- see EDIT.

Comment: I had thought of the copy of PK columns to track changes, but the two issues I see with it are: (1) You lose integrity because the original value is not part of the key. (2) The SQL becomes more complicated to create a list of all changes related to row. I don't think there is a good solution for row level auditing Natural Keys tables if there is possibility that the values of the keys would change. Since you have put this much effort into the answer I'll mark as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @DamirSudarevic, because I already have columns for ModifedDate and ModifedBy, I don't add extra columns for ChangedAt and ChangedBy. I do add one extra column for the Audit table called IsDelete (bool) that tracks if the change was a delete.  To avoid errors with duplicate PK, I create a composite PK on audit tables with the ID, ModifedDate and IsDelete.

Comment: @Josh -- The current key will track the row changes. ON UPDATE CASCADE propagates the key to ALL records. The _CPY field shows previously captured keys. Try it on an example.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, that natural key in particular is odd.
There is no restriction for you to have both sets of keys, natural and surrogate.
I would mix both tables i'd use LogID for PK and create a unique index for LogType+ModifiedDate, so that way you have a single field PK for joining tables (which i think is a good thing) and you have your Business/Natural Key (still unique just not Primary) for whatever you need it.

Comment: The goal of asking this question is if someone knows of approach that I could have an Audit table with just Natural Keys.

Comment: the thing is, the primary key is not meant to be changed, it is the record identifier, if a field of a composite key changes, you get a new record. And the only way to track that kind of change is with a trigger. Thats why you have two keys, a single-field PK for linking records and your composite key for business uniqueness. And actually, your surrogate key solution needs its own independent PK something like LogAuditID, and LogID is just a FK.

Comment: Surrogate Keys shouldn't change, but a Natural Key can change and do change. When it changes you need to have Cascade Updates on so that it updates all FK references. Composite Keys are fine to use for PK, but I agree they are more difficult to create references. Almost all database schemes I've created use Surrogate Keys, I'm looking for suggestions for when I have a Natural Key and need to audit.

Comment: Primary keys should not change ever. If they do then you should not use the natural key as the primary key but use it as a unique index. I do not see a way to audit if you allow the PK to change without adding a surrogate key field to relate to the audit table (It doesn't have to be the PK I suppose.) You could call it AuditKey if you want.